# Different performance in SQL Server for the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I have two queries that show a big difference in performance.

The two queries are similar, but different values are selected. One query results in 359.890 rows and time of execution is faster than the other query, while the other query only returns 51.439 rows.

I don't understand why the query with fewer rows has a higher execution time?

I suppose the problem is in the join with `vd.MComercial = m.Material_Comercial` or `and vd.codigo_organizacion = M.Codigo_Organizacion`, but I dont know how to analyze these results. I've seen the field's values and they are same.

If I try to copy the values inside a temporal table the performance is good. Less 4s. I do not get why this would be so. Does somebody know how I can analyze this problem?

```
select COUNT(*) 
from _T_VENTAS_DIARIAS as VD 
left join _CAT_materiales M on vd.MComercial = m.Material_Comercial
                               and vd.codigo_organizacion = M.Codigo_Organizacion
where Año = 2014 
      and  Semana = 27
      and M.Material_Comercial is not null
```

Returns "359890".

```
select vd.codigo_organizacion, sum(Vta_Bruta)   
from _T_VENTAS_DIARIAS as VD 
left join _CAT_materiales M on vd.MComercial = m.Material_Comercial
                               and vd.codigo_organizacion = M.Codigo_Organizacion
where Año = 2014 
      and Semana = 27     
      and M.Material_Comercial is not null          
group by vd.codigo_organizacion
```

This query is faster, <4s.

```
select COUNT(*) from _T_VENTAS_DIARIAS as VD 
left join  _CAT_materiales M on vd.MComercial = m.Material_Comercial
                                and vd.codigo_organizacion = M.Codigo_Organizacion
where Año = 2014 
      and Semana = 28      
      and vd.dia_calendario = 'lunes'
      and M.Material_Comercial is not null
```

Returns "51439".

```
select vd.codigo_organizacion, sum(Vta_Bruta)                          
from _T_VENTAS_DIARIAS as VD 
left join _CAT_materiales M on vd.MComercial = m.Material_Comercial
                               and vd.codigo_organizacion = M.Codigo_Organizacion
where Año = 2014 
      and  Semana = 28    
      and vd.dia_calendario = 'lunes' 
      and M.Material_Comercial is not null                          
group by vd.codigo_organizacion
```

This query is slow: > 120.

Comment: What is your schema/your indexes?

Comment: This is going to be close to impossible to solve without knowing the schema/indexes as already requested, but also the execution plan for each query. It would also be worth running with the option `SET STATISTICS IO ON` to show the number of reads for each query.

Comment: My biggest guess is going to be that you don't have an index that includes `vd.dia_calendario` so for each row it's got to do a text search for the value you're selecting, in this case, `lunes`.  A larger dataset isn't necessarily going to be slower just because it's got greater volume.  It's the searching that can be expensive.

Comment: Post the execution plans

Comment: You should think about posting this on [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). They will write the same comments so you should upgrade the question before posting it there.

Comment: I can't upload  image of execution plans.  And schema/indexes how can I to find this information en SQL server? thanks

Comment: You can upload the pics of the execution plan to imgur or some other host and post the links here.  Try that, and you can look at the indexes for a table in SQL Server by right-clicking the table looking at the properties.  One of the properties you can look at is indexes.  That's if you have access to the IDE.  Otherwise you need to query sys.indexes joined on sys.tables by `object_id=object_id`.

Comment: Indexes for table _CAT_Materiales <br/>´Name Policy Health State
IDX_CAT_Materiales_Codorg (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) 
IDX_MAteriales_ ME (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) 
IDX_Materiales_Familia (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) 
IDX_Materiales_Marca (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) 
IDX_Materiales_Organizacion (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) 
IDX_Materiales_SubDivision (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) 
IDX_Materiales_SubFamilia (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)'

Comment: @Maurice  plan execution [link]http://imgur.com/gallery/O1eGsEz/new)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your execution plan (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIXuw.jpg), 99% of the cost of your query is a table scan on _T_VENTAS_DIARIAS.  Create an index on the table like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <index name> ON _T_VENTAS_DIARIAS (Año, Semana, Dia_Calendario);
```

Try that, and rerun your query.  It should be much faster.  Obviously I'm assuming that Año and Semana are columns in _T_VENTAS_DIARIAS.  If they're not, remove them from the index create statement.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice. the performance is very faster. so Do you know the information of the indixes of SQL? I like to learn to use correctly

Comment: Glad to hear it.  You can start here on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx